# what can be done if shortcuts stop working?

Tags: 15.04, shortcut-keys

Suddenly some basic shortcuts no longer work. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> does not open a terminal windows for example.

Why not? What can be done about it? Neither does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> lock the system. What can be done about it?

Comment: Are those shortcuts *enabled* in **System Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** tab ?

Comment: @hg8 Yes they are.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `settings`-->`keyboard`-->`Shorcuts`.From there you can setting it back.

As an example for `Lock`. In `Shortcuts` go to `System` and Click `Lock Screen` and set the combination back by pressing the combination key.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it doesn't work. I wish there was some error log to look at. But it seems none of my keyboard shortcuts are working.

Comment: does that mean the shortcuts are there but not working?

Comment: Yes that is the case. The shortcuts are listed in the settings but they do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a plug an play keyboard? Here is some general help that you can read to create user hot keys. Hope this helps you out!   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts [en](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts)